# Selenium webdriver, Python - target partial CSS selector?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to target specific CSS elements on a page, but the problem is that they have varying selector names.  For instance, `input#dp156435476435.textinput.wihtinnextyear.datepicker.hasDatepicker.error`.  I need to target the CSS because i am specifcally looking for the `.error` at the end of the element, and that is only in the CSS (testing error validation for fields on a website.  I know if I was targeting class/name/href/id/etc, I could use xpath, but I'm not aware of a partial CSS selector in selenium webdriver.  Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Have you considered just iterating through the entire document tree and testing each element for your CSS attribute?

Answer (score 3):

The period/full stop is a partial class selector:

```
span.error
```

would find:

```
<span class="error" />
<span class="error warning" />
<span class="critical error" />
```

You also have:

```
span[class^='error']
```

(begins with)

```
span[class$='error']
```

(ends with)

```
span[class*='error']
```

(contains)

Answer (score 0):

If the page has similar elements, you can combine what Arran said like so:

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector( "input[id^='dp'][class*='nextyear'][class$='error']" )
```

Answer (score 0):

css=span.error -- Error

css=span.warning -- Warning

css=span.critical -- Critical Error

Simple above are the CSS Selectors we can use.